# How to change the spacing between equations and texts in a global way

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I want to change the spacing between equations and text with the following code. But all the text in the article changes to 10pt.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 5\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\makeatother
```

Who has another way that keeps the current font size?

Comment: this definition is very strange what is the intended use? You are redefining `\large` but then setting `\normalsize` ?

Comment: @David Carlisle Changing back to 'nomalsize', the problem still exists.

Comment: you have so far given no clues as to what "the problem" is. You show a definition but do not show how you use it and you say that the problem is that the text changes to 10pt but 10pt is the default and expected size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto\normalsize{%
  \abovedisplayskip 5\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
  \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\makeatother
```

However, I have some doubts the values you're setting.

Comment: changing 1 to 5 will be better.

Comment: @Kuttens I don't think so, but I updated the answer based on your edit.